# CSS properties of two divs - not matching width as expected

Tags: css

I have a title bar with a content div beneath it, that I would expect to match in width. The content div, however, appears to be offset very slightly to the left, as well as being slightly narrower as evidenced on the right hand side in this image:

[image]

The title div also has a little dynamic JS to make it "stick" to the top of the page, thus the "stick" portion of the css is also included.

**Title div**

```
#menu {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0.5ex;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0B0000;
    color: #ffffff;
    height: 16px;
}
#menu.stick {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

**Root background**

```
#bodystyle {
    background-color: #efefef;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

**Page Content**

```
#pagecontent {
    /*width: 100%;*/ <=== This being set does not remedy the problem.
    padding-left: 7%;     Instead the div expands to the right hand 
    padding-right: 7%;    edge of the page.
    padding-top: 3%;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Could the edge of the title possibly be affected by the text padding? I would have thought not, myself. Or, is this expected behaviour? Ideally I would like both sides of both title and content divs to be utterly uniform.

Comment: I am not sure i understand your question completly, fiddle would help alot. But, do u have box-sizing?

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

Comment: @GoranJakovljevic Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5y6383fz/ The JS isn't working as it does locally, but that's namely because I have nowhere to host the .js file. Anyway, look at the right hand side of the content and title elements - see how they're out of line?

Comment: The menu item is overhanging as it's padding isn't included in its size. As @GoranJakovljevic said,you can fix this by setting box-sizing: border-box; on *, or just on the menu div: https://jsfiddle.net/5y6383fz/1/

Comment: @phynam Ok, that seems to work for the width, however the height of the box is now compromised resulting in this: http://i.imgur.com/SRAY0TD.png Is there a way to apply box-sizing by width alone?

Comment: This is because you have a height set on it which doesn't account for the padding, if you remove the height, or add the amount of extra padding - it will work.

Comment: @phynam Oh! Fair enough. If I were to need to change the height again, would I thus modify the text padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer here.

So what you want to do is add box-sizing to all alements:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

this could go just after your css reset. This way when you set the width of an element, that's the width that it is, as padding is now happening inside that width.

Next for height, you have 2 options, fixed height of that nav or to add padding to it. I would go with fixed height and also add line-height to be same height in order to center text in it.

Thats it.